# How to view Clang AST?

Tags: clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to get hold on Clang. So, I would like to view the AST generated by Clang after parsing the given program. Is it possible to dump AST in .dot or .viz format? Is there any tool out there?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Clang supports showing the AST with Graphviz's `dotty` -- you can grab the temporary .dot file generated (name is printed out) to get the graph source.

```
clang -cc1 -ast-view your_file.c
```

You can also print to the command line with:

```
clang -cc1 -ast-dump your_file.c
```

or:

```
clang -cc1 -ast-print your_file.c
```

or in 3.3:

```
clang -cc1 -ast-dump-xml your_file.c
```

but this [was removed](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=127141) later as pointed by Lukas Kubanek in the comment.

Comment: The XML printer is no longer supported. See http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=127141

Comment: `-ast-view` also seems to require compile time support, which is not on by default on Ubuntu 14.04 :-( `-ast-dump` works beautifully. What is `-ast-print` supposed to do? It just prints the code itself with some empty lines afterwards.

Comment: According to the revision comment the xml printer never actually worked properly.

Comment: In recent clang you can also use `-ast-dump=json`, very useful! You can add this to your answer, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 70):

The method with `-cc1` invocation [will have problem with includes](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/FAQ.html#id2) and recognizing C++.

For full-featured parsing, use:

```
clang -Xclang -ast-dump file.cpp
```

Comment: Ah, this is the switch I always forget. This prints the AST with pretty colours in Windows ^^

Answer (score 6):

For viewing the AST

`clang-check -ast-dump filename.c`

For to view the specific functions in a program

`clang-check -ast-dump -ast-dump-filter=function_name filename.c`

Answer (score 3):

I am using following:

```
clang my_file.h -I. -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only -fno-color-diagnostics -Wno-visibility
```

IMHO This is more suitable for machine parsing.

Comment: When I run this on a single file from a library I get errors about missing header files, even with the `-fsyntax-only` flag. Any ideas?