# How can I know the implicit conversion used by the compiler?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, implicit-conversion

In a big project, I have this code, compiling well, but I don't understand why.

```
std::vector<std::string> foo;
if(foo == 1) // Here is the error, the good code is "if(foo.size() == 1)"
  do_something();
```

In a simple test main, it doesn't compile. I suppose the compiler finds an operator somewhere and uses it with implicit conversion.

**Is there a way to know which one is used ?**

I use gcc 8.5.0 with warning options `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion`.

In order to understand which kind of code can induce this beheviour, here is an example of a code having such an implicit conversion:

```
# include <string>
# include <vector>
# include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
        A() = default;
        A(A const&) = default;
        A(std::vector<std::string> const&) {}
        A(int) {}
};
bool operator==(A const&, A const&) { return true; }

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> foo;
    if(foo == 1)
        std::cout << "foo == 1" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this is working, this is for sure by a custom operator overload. With the debugger, it should be possible to step into that operator. IDEs may also provide aid (but for me, IntelliSense fails always in the moment when it would help most...)

Comment: is it really a `std::vector` ? Its easy to rule out much of the usual possiblities. It cannot be via a member, it cannot be something that is found via ADL, acutally I am not sure how it can work at all

Comment: The problem is most likely in code you do not show. Do you have a class that is implicitly convertible to std::string? Which by itself has an implicit constructor accepting an int? Maybe... Go through your code base, look for ALL constructors with ONE argument and make them `explicit`. Also remove ANY implicit conversion operators you have on classes of your own and replace them with explicit typecast operators or getters returning a member value.

Comment: Terminology: a **cast** is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. So there's no such thing as an "implicit cast"; a cast is always explicit. The question is about an **implicit conversion**.

Comment: Have a look at those guidlines [Avoid implicit conversion functions](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c164-avoid-implicit-conversion-operators), [C.46: By default, declare single-argument constructors explicit](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c46-by-default-declare-single-argument-constructors-explicit)

Comment: Can't you get your IDE to help? Change it to `if( operator==(foo, 1) )` and jump to the definition of `operator==`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Here is an example of such a code : https://codeshare.io/w9dw69

Comment: @Caduchon Yeah, the perils of implicit conversions

Comment: @PepijnKramer, the rest of the code is thousands classes, using several libs... I need a tool to find it. ^_^' The debugger is a good idea, a warning from gcc could be better.

Comment: @Caduchon ... and what about using the IDE like I suggested?

Comment: @PeteBecker right. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: The way to do it is to have a properly configured IDE (at least VSCode + Clangd can do it), then (for VSC) Ctrl+Click (or Alt+Click depending on the settings) the `==`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai : I added an example

Comment: Well, my IDE (QtCreator) seems not well configured. It doesn't show me this information.

Comment: I remember similar question that was asking to determine the function that will be selected by overload resolution, iirc there was no way (at least not in code, and portable)

Comment: As spotted by Pepjin Kramer, mark the `A` constructor from `vector` as `explicit` and you'll understand what is happening: https://godbolt.org/z/ojY6h18bK. The compiler implicitly converted your `vector` to a `A` for which `operator ==` is defined. Probably not what you want. Implicit conversion rules are tricky. I prefer not to rely on them and control my conversions...

Comment: Well sometimes the tool is your IDE and regular expressions for find all.  E.g. `^\s*operator\s*\w+\(\w*\)` for finding declarations of conversion operators.  And this one will look for things that look like constructors with only one argument `^\s*\w+\s*\([^,]+\)`

Comment: There's nothing in the C++ language for this. Any solution here will take the form of a compiler-specific feature or tool. Some source code annotation tools, like doxygen, might be able to hunt down and compile all the conversion operators in an easily-searchable form, with a pointer to the original source.

Comment: @Oersted : it's just an example of a possible source of the bug in order to illustrate that it's possible to happen.

Comment: I found a trick (see my own answer).

Comment: [cppinsights.io](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=c3RydWN0IFMKewogIG9wZXJhdG9yIGJvb2woKSBjb25zdCB7IHJldHVybiB0cnVlOyB9Cn07CgppbnQgbWFpbigpCnsKICAgIGlmIChTKCkpIHsKICAgIH0KfQ==&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0) might help (or dump ast from clang tool directly, see [how-to-view-clang-ast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560019/how-to-view-clang-ast)).

Answer (score 5):

**Answering my own question**

In order to find the source of the implicit conversion, I created another source of implicit conversion. Then, the compiler can't choose and shows the possibilities.

Example:

```
# include <string>
# include <vector>
# include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
        A() = default;
        A(A const&) = default;
        A(std::vector<std::string> const&) {}
        A(int) {}
};
bool operator==(A const&, A const&) { return true; }

class B
{
    public:
        B() = default;
        B(B const&) = default;
        B(std::vector<std::string> const& x) {}
        B(int x) {}
};
bool operator==(B const&, B const&) { return false; }

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> foo;
    if(foo == 1)
        std::cout << "foo == 1" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

GCC output:

```
test_vector.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test_vector.cpp:28:9: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ and ‘int’)
  if(foo == 1)
     ~~~~^~~~
test_vector.cpp:13:6: note: candidate: ‘bool operator==(const A&, const A&)’
 bool operator==(A const&, A const&) { return true; }
      ^~~~~~~~
test_vector.cpp:23:6: note: candidate: ‘bool operator==(const B&, const B&)’
 bool operator==(B const&, B const&) { return false; }
      ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: you need to consider that the conversion via `A` requires to convert both arguments. Your conversion via `B` will be ranked worse when the conversion via `A` requires only 1. Not sure if I can epxress myself clearly :D see here: https://godbolt.org/z/8qMGohnv5

Comment: in other words, it might be necessary to also try an `operator==(std::vector<std::string>,something that can be converted from int)` and `operator==(something that can be converted from the vector,int)`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, of course. It's a trick to help to have more information from the compiler. Not a real solution.

Comment: yes I understand. but your trick may fail to find the `operator==` that is called, as in my example code, and as mentioned there is a way to find the `operator==` in that case too

Comment: Just as a footnote for future readers:  what we have here is a lack of `explicit` for the constructors, so the compiler will promiscuously implicitly convert the arguments.  It is unfortunate that `explicit` is an explicit opt-in, rather than the default that has to be opt-out-of.  In the words of Kate Gregory, **all the defaults are wrong**.

Answer (score 1):

Without introducing new temporary source code to flush out an elusive implicit conversion method,
you may bring it to light by generating a verbose, unoptimised assembly listing,
with demangled identifiers, of a source file in which the problem implicit conversion is invoked.
You will be able to find an explicit invocation of the implicit conversion method in that listing. For example (slightly adapting your posted code):

Suppose `a.hpp` is the header file, buried in your project, in which the problem implicit conversion is declared.

**a.hpp**

```
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP

# include <string>
# include <vector>

class A
{
    public:
        A() = default;
        A(A const&) = default;
        A(std::vector<std::string> const&) {}
        A(int) {}
};
bool operator==(A const&, A const&) { return true; }

#endif
```

And `main.cpp` is a source file in which the problem conversion is invoked.

**main.cpp**

```
# include <string>
# include <vector>
# include "a.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> foo;
    if(foo == 1)
        std::cout << "foo == 1" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

We can generate a verbose, unoptimised, demangled assembly listing of `main.cpp`
with a command of the form:

```
$ g++ -S -o - -fverbose-asm [other-option ... ] main.cpp | c++filt > main.txt
```

Here, `g++ -S -o - -fverbose-asm main.cpp` writes a verbose unoptimised
assembly listing, but with *mangled* identifiers, to the standard output. Then `| c++filt > main.txt` pipes it
through `c++filt`, to demangle the identifiers, and directs the output of that to `main.txt`.
(I call the output `main.txt`, rather than `main.s`, because with demangled identifiers
the listing is no longer well-formed assembly code).

The option `-fverbose-asm` has the invaluable effect of interjecting the C++ source statements into
the assembly instructions that result from them.

Concretely, we may use:

```
$ g++ -S -o - -fverbose-asm -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp | c++filt > main.txt
```

The resulting `main.txt` is a large file to survey. But our source editor, or the `cat -n` command,
will give us the source line number of a known invocation of the problem conversion:

```
$ cat -n main.cpp
 1  # include <string>
 2  # include <vector>
 3  #include <iostream>
 4  # include "a.hpp"
 5  
 6  int main()
 7  {
 8      std::vector<std::string> foo;
 9      if(foo == 1)                               // <- Here!
10          std::cout << "foo == 1" << std::endl;
11      return 0;
12  }
```

Then we can easily locate in `main.txt` all of the demangled assembly code
generated by that line:

```
# main.cpp:9:     if(foo == 1)
    leaq    -49(%rbp), %rax #, tmp88
    movl    $1, %esi    #,
    movq    %rax, %rdi  # tmp88,
    call    A::A(int)   #
# main.cpp:9:     if(foo == 1)
    leaq    -48(%rbp), %rdx #, tmp89
    leaq    -50(%rbp), %rax #, tmp90
    movq    %rdx, %rsi  # tmp89,
    movq    %rax, %rdi  # tmp90,
    call    A::A(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)    #
# main.cpp:9:     if(foo == 1)
    leaq    -49(%rbp), %rdx #, tmp91
    leaq    -50(%rbp), %rax #, tmp92
    movq    %rdx, %rsi  # tmp91,
    movq    %rax, %rdi  # tmp92,
    call    operator==(A const&, A const&)  #
# main.cpp:9:     if(foo == 1)
    testb   %al, %al    # retval.0_9
    je  .L9 #,
```

Here, we see that the first function call generated to compile the line `if(foo == 1)` is the conversion constructor `A::A(int)` - the obvious culprit.

A implicit conversion method that is giving us grief need not be an implicit conversion constructor. It might also
be an implicit conversion operator that converts its containing class `A` to some other type `B`. In that case we would be looking for the likes of

```
call    A::operator B() const
```

in the demangled assembly resulting from a source line where the implicit conversion is invoked.

Answer (score -1):

The answer of [@Caduchon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3378179/caduchon) seems to work in this case, but is incomplete (as [@463035818_is_not_an_ai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/463035818-is-not-an-ai) has mentioned).

The scenario that `(foo == 1)` returns `true` can be caused due to many operator overloads. But all those can be categorized almost in two groups.

**Group 1:**

```
// 1st overload
class A
{
    public:
        A() = default;
        A(A const&) = default;
        A(std::vector<std::string> /* const & */) {}
        A(int /* const & */) {}
};
bool operator==(A const&, A const&) { return true; }
```

**Group 2:**

```
// 2nd overload
bool operator==(std::vector<std::string> /* const & */, int /* const & */) { return true; }
```

The other overloads can be acheived by modiifying the cv-qualifiers of `std::string` and `int` in the above two overloads.

A detailed code for all the overloads is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/sr3oKdEdr)

**But the given two overloads are special.**

 The presence of the 1st overload will generate ambiguity if any other overload of Group 1 is present (and only if no overload from Group 2 is present).

 Similarly, the presence of the 2nd overload will generate ambiguity if any other overload of Group 2 is present.

So, to completely resolve the issue,

1. Copy the 1st overload in your code and check for ambiguity.
2. Remove the ambiguity found in step 1.
3. Remove the 1st overload and copy the 2nd overload and check for ambiguity.
4. Remove the ambiguity found in step 2.
5. Remove the 2nd overload.

Now, `(foo==1)` shall raise an error.

Comment: your 2 alternatives are still incomplete. YOu only consider 2 or 0 conversions, but when the overload has 1 you will miss it. Seee this example, where there are 3 overloads of different ranks not leading to ambiguity: https://godbolt.org/z/Ehjaj371M

Comment: and then we didnt consider templates yet....